# Sorting sublist in common lisp

Tags: sorting, lisp, common-lisp, sublist

Very Simple

with this, `(sort L #'> :key #'second))`, I can sort, `(((C) 1) ((D) 1) ((E) 1) ((F) 1) ((G) 1) ((H) 1) ((B) 3) ((A) 8))`

But now I want to sort, `((((A) 8)) (((B) 3)) (((C) 1)) (((D) 1)) (((E) 1)) (((F) 1)) (((G) 1)) (((H) 1)))`.

What do i need to do to, `(sort L #'> :key #'second))`, to get the second list to sort?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I hope I understand your question correctly.

What you need is `:key (lambda (x) (second (car x)))`.

However, [you do not even need](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_car_c.htm) `lambda`:

```
(cadar '(((A) 8)))
==> 8
```

so `:key #'cadar` is your friend.